# How to create new issue from slack to redmine?

Tags: slack-api, slack

I need create issues from #channel in Slack and post it to Redmine.
How can i do it? Is it possible?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://api.slack.com/slash-commands

Comment: also creating issues via redmine api: https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues#Creating-an-issue